# How to use prewritten commands in Vim

Tags: vim, command, customization

Sometimes it's boring to rewrite similar commands over and over again, so I want to prewrite all of them, saving them into one customized command and use it once and for all. However, as the new command I'll use is only needed for the file I'm currently using, I really don't want to bother changing vimrc file. So here is my question, is it possible to prewrite a command into a file and load it into vim then use it for one time use? If possible, how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: OK, more explicitly, I want to use
`%s/a[i]/b[i]/g`
for multiple a[i] and b[i]. As I can only type one line in command mode, and it's not convenient to change values in commands. I think I'd better create a new command in another file and source it like William suggested. I'm not sure it's the best way, but that's what I can currently think of...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just source the file:

```
:source /p/a/t/h
```

Also, you can use an autocmd in .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.whatever source /p/a/t/h
```

Or, rather than sourcing the file, just put the commands directly in the `autocmd`.

Comment: Additionally, you can also setup some AutoCmd so they're automatically loaded based on the file you're opening.

Answer (score 2):

Without a concrete example, it's hard to advise. It sounds like you would like to define custom commands for a particular filetype, like this:

```
:command -buffer ComplexSubstitute %substitute/foo/bar/g
```

See `:help user-commands`. For the buffer-scope, put them into `~/.vim/ftplugin/<filetype>_commands.vim` or so. With `:filetype plugin on`, these files are sourced automatically. Alternatively, you can define buffer-local `:map`pings in much the same way there.

Comment: Well, actually it's not for a filetype, just for a single file, I need to change multiple patterns with another series of patterns. In normal mode, I have to use ":%s/a[i]/b[i]/g" for a lot of times, so I really want to make all of them into one command and run it for one time.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat a previous command quickly, you can try my [redocommand plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1661). It repeats the last command from the history that contains the passed pattern. Example:

```
:%substitute/foo/bar/g
" ... some time later ...
:R %s
```

With the built-in commands, you can start repeating the command (`:%s`), then complete the last such command with <kbd>↑</kbd>.

Comment: It's a nice plugin~ Though I still have to do the looping for the different patterns I repeat the command for each time. But thanks, it helps~

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's only for one time, there is a natural(normal) way

1. Write your command in a **single line** in any file. You can yank it to any other file you want to work on.
2. On this line, `^y$` to yank the code. Don't `yy` otherwise carriage will be yanked
3. Go to command line by `:`, hit `C-r "` to paste it to command line. `<CR>` to profit.

A bit hassle but it works. I do that sometime as well:)